# Should I ever do "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" on a mission critical server?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no," but there's more to this question.

If `dist-upgrade` often downloads kernel upgrades, will my Ubuntu server always be stuck at a certain kernel if I always just do `sudo apt-get upgrade`? Or do I not really need the kernel upgrades? I assume I'll still receive security patches and other software updates?

Comment: Why are you doing upgrades on a production rig without testing anyway?

Comment: Test, Test some more, then test again to be sure. And before you do it in live, make sure you have a backup :)

Comment: @DeerHunter Testing what exactly? How exactly do I "test" on a production server?

Comment: You have to  test all of your mission-critical software. Upgrades may break some functions or components.

Comment: @DeerHunter But it's kind of a catch-22. How can I test mission critical software without actually upgrading it first?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack If it is mission critical, then there should be a separate test environment. That one should be as close a copy of the production environment as possible. The test environment is where you test things, including upgrades, performance testing etc. It is also where you test both backups and restores. If you can't afford a test environment you are prioritizing wrong.